# Clojure/ClojureScript: How to plug in custom print implementation for EDN tag literals?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, edn

I have a record, an instance of and I print it to EDN string:

```
(ns my)
(defrecord Ref [type id])
(def rich (->Ref :Person 42)
(pr-str rich)
```

I would like to get `"#my.Ref [:Person 42]`.

But I get `"#my.Ref{:type :Person, :id 23}"`.

Sow how can I plug in my custom implementation for printing instances of `Ref`?

Comment: Can I ask what difference it makes to you how it looks?

Comment: The vector has positional values instead of named values. It  takes laess space and is easier to read for very frequent values in my documents.

Answer (score 5):

In CLJS this is done via the `cljs.core/IPrintWithWriter` protocol.

```clj
(extend-type Ref
  IPrintWithWriter
  (-pr-writer [this writer opts]
    (-write writer "#my.Ref ")
    (-pr-writer [(:type this) (:id this)] writer opts)))
```

In CLJ it is done via the `clojure.core/print-method` multimethod.

```clj
(defmethod print-method Ref [this writer]
  (.write writer "#my.Ref ")
  (print-method [(:type this) (:id this)] writer))
```

Comment: Specifically: `(defmethod print-method Ref [this ^java.io.Writer w] (.write w (str "#my.Ref [" (:type this) " " (:id this) "]")))`

Comment: This is not recommended. The issue with the above is that it relies on `.toString` of the given types of `:type` and `:id`, e.g. it won't work properly for UUIDs. Always best to fall back on the actual print implementation, than blindly `str`-ing things together. You are given the writer, use that directly and don't concatenate strings together manually. I added a full example.